# Is there a way to use Bitwise Operators instead of multiple Ternary Operators?

Tags: math, logic, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

Is there a way to get a result of applying a ternary `?:` operator to individual bits without actually computing it one bit at a time, i.e. using some combination of *and*-s, *or*-s, *xor*-s, and *not*-s?

In other words, given we have 3 `int`s (regardless of bit length): `a`, `b`, and mask `m`, the result `r` should basically be: `r = m ? a : b`, except on a per-bit basis.

Assuming `a = 0b0101; b = 0b1110;` and `m = 0b0110`, the result `r` should be `0b1100`. So, if bit *n* in mask `m` is `1` (true), use the *n*-th bit from `a`; otherwise (if bit *n* in mask `m` is `0` (false)) then use the *n*-th bit from `b`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `m`, `a` and `b` are all guaranteed to be 0 or 1, then `m ? a : b` is equivalent to `(m && a) || (!m && b)`. You can see that by injecting `m=0` or `m=1` in the formula and simplifying it.

This works bitwise too; **bitwise not** is usually noted `~`; so the "bitwise ternary operator" that you are looking for can be expressed as:

```
(m&a)|((~m)&b)
```

Answer (score 0):

For explanatory purposes, I soon realized that the problem can be thought of as taking all valid `1`s from `a` and `b` by using the mask `m` and combining the results. Then the problem becomes trivial, as illustrated in the truth table:

```
-------------------------------------------
         a:   0   0   0   0   1   1   1   1
         b:   1   1   0   0   1   1   0   0
         m:   1   0   1   0   1   0   1   0   // 1 = the positions from a; 0 = positions from b

        ~m:   0   1   0   1   0   1   0   1
 
 x = m & a:   0   0   0   0   1   0   1   0   // take all valid 1s from a
y = ~m & b:   0   1   0   0   0   1   0   0   // take all valid 1s from b

 r = x | y:   0   1   0   0   1   1   1   0   // combine: r = (m & a) | (~m & b)
-------------------------------------------
  EXPECTED:   0   1   0   0   1   1   1   0
```

An alternative implementation using *xor*-s: `r = b ^ (m & (a ^ b))`

```
-------------------------------------------
         a:   0   0   0   0   1   1   1   1
         b:   1   1   0   0   1   1   0   0
         m:   1   0   1   0   1   0   1   0   // 1 = the positions from a; 0 = positions from b

 u = a ^ b:   1   1   0   0   0   0   1   1
 v = m & u:   1   0   0   0   0   0   1   0

 r = b ^ v:   0   1   0   0   1   1   1   0
-------------------------------------------
  EXPECTED:   0   1   0   0   1   1   1   0
```